# Adding audioClip from the Resources folder through code

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

How can I add and play short audioClip by name in code in Unity?
I tested a lot of samples from the Internet but anyone doesn't work.

```
    AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.Play((AudioClip)Resources.Load("clip1"));​
```

To the second line:

> Assets/Resources/ClickAction.cs(14,55): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `'

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `Resources.Load`? Is the Audio file in the Resources folder. Where is the Audio file located?

Comment: yes, it is in Resources. But I really don't haven't got a clue how to modify that

Comment: You want to upload a picture of the folder structure and the name of the audio file? That will help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: no, I want only upload a sound. That will be in one folder, but it's in Resource folder now

Comment: Sorry for that. I meant to say you should upload a picture/screenshot of the Resources folder structure in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry! I misunderstood. Done ;)

Comment: That's fine. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AudioSource.Play()` does not take `AudioClip` as a parameter.

`AudioSource.PlayOneShot()` does. [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568850/3785314) also talked about this except that no code example was provided in his answer.

This is what the play prototype looks like:

```
public void Play();
public void Play(ulong delay);
```

None of them takes `AudioClip` as parameter.

So it should be:

```
AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
audio.PlayOneShot((AudioClip)Resources.Load("clip1"));
```

You can still use the the `Play()` function from your question but you must first assign `AudioSource.clip` with `(AudioClip)Resources.Load("clip1");` before calling the `Play()` function.

So, this should work too:

```
AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
audio.clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("clip1");
audio.Play();
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you so much for your help and explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean "doesn't work"? I don't have Unity installed right now, but looking through documentation it seems that you should use PlayOneShot instead of Play:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html

Comment: That's only for adding an audio file from Inspector. I need do that in a script